# Tensor Product: Use of Universal Mapping Property

Tags: tensor-products

I'm reading [this](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/27.pdf) paper and on page 394 proposition 2.0.4 has a proof.  In this proof $B:M\times N \to Q$ is defined as the $0$-map.  Assuming it makes sense to define $B$ this way then I can follow the rest of the proof.  Therefore, my question is, why is setting $B$ to be the $0$-map the only sensible thing to do?  I mean couldn't you define $B$ to be any number of maps giving you a completely different map for $q$?

EDIT:  Based on an answer that was given maybe my question should be, why is the $0$-map from $M\times N\to M\otimes N$ the only $R$-bilinear map?

Answer (score 1):

The map $B$ can be *any* $R$-bilinear map. In particular, $B$ can be the zero map.

Comment: So if I were to define $B$ as any other map than the $0$-map I would find that it isn't $R$-bilinear?  Or, is it enough that since $B$ and $q$ definitely factor through I automatically know that there are no other bilinear maps that factor through?